# Is there a nice way to check if numpy array elements are within a range?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to write:

```
assert np.all(0 < a < 2)
```

where `a` is a `numpy` array, but it doesn't work.  What's a nice way to write this?

Comment: (In case there are questions, I have to run for now.  Hopefully the question is clear enough.)

Comment: Similar to this question [Easy way to test if each element in an numpy array lies between two values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542240/easy-way-to-test-if-each-element-in-an-numpy-array-lies-between-two-values) , but with an extra call to `np.all()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

```
>>> a = np.repeat(1, 10)
>>> np.logical_and(a > 0, a < 2).all()
True
```

or using `&`.

```
>>> ((0 < a) & (a < 2)).all()
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this within NumPy with either:

```
import numpy as np


def between_all_and(arr, a, b):
    return np.all((arr > a) & (arr < b))
```

or:

```
import numpy as np


def between_and_all(arr, a, b):
    return np.all(arr > a) and np.all(arr < b)
```

(or, equivalently, by calling [`np.ndarray.all()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html) instead of [`np.all()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html#numpy.all)).

Note that `np.all()` could be replaced by `all()`, which may be faster for smaller inputs, but it is much slower on larger ones.

While they give the same results, they both have sub-optimal short-circuiting properties:

- `between_all_and()` ("all of and") will compute both `arr > a` and `arr < b` arrays before accessing short-circuited code (`np.all()`)
- `between_and_all()` ("and of all") will not short-circuit on `arr < b` before all `arr > a` tests are performed.

On randomly distributed arrays, this means that the two may have very different timings.

Alternatively, one can use a loop-based implementation accelerated with Numba:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def between_all_nb(arr, a, b):
    arr = arr.ravel()
    for x in arr:
        if x <= a or x >= b:
            return False
    return True
```

This has much better short-circuiting properties, and does not create potentially large temporary arrays.

---

As per @NeilG comments, I have also included a `jax`-accelerated version.

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp


@jax.jit
def between_and_all_jax(arr, a, b):
    return jnp.all((arr > a) & (arr < b))
```

---

## Benchmarks

One can produce some benchmarks on batches (of size `m`) of arrays (of size `n`) containing random numbers to get some ideas on which approaches are faster and by how much.

In fact, assuming an array of uniformly distributed random numbers in the [0, 1] range, if one checks for different ranges, it is possible to produce cases with different short-circuiting:

- an "average case" for a range like (0.0, 0.999)
- a "worst case" (no short-circuiting) for a range like (-1.0, 2.0)
- a "best case" (potentially immediate short-circuiting) for a range like (2.0, 3.0)

The benchmarks are produced with:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def benchmark(
    funcs,
    args=None,
    kws=None,
    ii=range(4, 24),
    m=2 ** 15,
    is_equal=np.allclose,
    seed=0,
    unit="ms",
    verbose=True
):
    labels = [func.__name__ for func in funcs]
    units = {"s": 0, "ms": 3, "µs": 6, "ns": 9}
    args = tuple(args) if args else ()
    kws = dict(kws) if kws else {}
    assert unit in units
    np.random.seed(seed)
    timings = {}
    for i in ii:
        n = 2 ** i
        k = 1 + m // n
        if verbose:
            print(f"i={i}, n={n}, m={m}, k={k}")
        arrs = np.random.random((k, n))
        base = np.array([funcs[0](arr, *args, **kws) for arr in arrs])
        timings[n] = []
        for func in funcs:
            res = np.array([func(arr, *args, **kws) for arr in arrs])
            is_good = is_equal(base, res)
            timed = %timeit -n 8 -r 8 -q -o [func(arr, *args, **kws) for arr in arrs]
            timing = timed.best / k
            timings[n].append(timing if is_good else None)
            if verbose:
                print(
                    f"{func.__name__:>24}"
                    f"  {is_good!s:5}"
                    f"  {timing * (10 ** units[unit]):10.3f} {unit}"
                    f"  {timings[n][0] / timing:5.1f}x")
    return timings, labels


def plot(timings, labels, title=None, xlabel="Input Size / #", unit="ms"):
    n_rows = 1
    n_cols = 3
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols, figsize=(8 * n_cols, 6 * n_rows), squeeze=False)
    units = {"s": 0, "ms": 3, "µs": 6, "ns": 9}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=timings, index=labels).transpose()
    
    base = df[[labels[0]]].to_numpy()
    (df * 10 ** units[unit]).plot(marker="o", xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=f"Best timing / {unit}", ax=axs[0, 0])
    (df / base * 100).plot(marker='o', xlabel=xlabel, ylabel='Relative speed / %', logx=True, ax=axs[0, 1])
    (base / df).plot(marker='o', xlabel=xlabel, ylabel='Speed Gain / x', ax=axs[0, 2])

    if title:
        fig.suptitle(title)
    fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
```

to be called as follows:

```py
funcs = between_all_and, between_and_all, between_all_nb, between_and_all_jax

avg_timings, avg_labels = benchmark(funcs, args=(0.01, 0.99), unit="µs", verbose=False)
wrs_timings, wrs_labels = benchmark(funcs, args=(-1.0, 2.0), unit="µs", verbose=False)
bst_timings, bst_labels = benchmark(funcs, args=(2.0, 3.0), unit="µs", verbose=False)
plot(avg_timings, avg_labels, "Average Case", unit="µs")
plot(wrs_timings, wrs_labels, "Worst Case", unit="µs")
plot(bst_timings, bst_labels, "Best Case", unit="µs")
```

to produce:

[image: bm_avg]

[image: bm_wrs]

[image: bm_bst]

These can be used to guess in which regimes which one is faster.

Note that the `jax` version may be running sub-optimally on the Colab Notebook used for the testing:

> WARNING:absl:No GPU/TPU found, falling back to CPU.

Typically, the Numba-based approach is not only the most efficient, but also the fastest.

Comment: Nice graphs.  If you're going to profile numba, would you mind comparing Jax as well?

Comment: @NeilG Can you recommend a `jax`-based version? If I just use `jax.numpy` in place of `numpy` I get nowhere interesting (much slower for smaller inputs, asymptotically approaching `numpy` for larger ones). If I add `@jax.jit` I get a type concretization error.

Comment: `@jax.jit
def jax_version(arr, a, b):
    print("Compiling", arr.shape)
    return jnp.all((arr > a) & (arr < b))`

Comment: @NeilG save for the print, that is exactly what I tried without success

Comment: Are you sure?  If you had concretization errors you probably used `and` or `np.all` instead of `jnp`.

Comment: My bad, I was using `and`, sorry. Anyway, I have now included your `jax`-based version. Unfortunately, it looks like it is not particularly fast, nor well optimized for short-circuiting.