# Problems with numpy.any() for condition checking

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

I want to start an `if` condition checking all elements in a previously defined array, for example:

```
import numpy as np

f = np.zeros(5)
if f[i]<100
   #do something
```

where `i` is supposed to check all the elements of `f`. I believe there is an easy way to do this in python instead of creating a loop searching all elements, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I tried to use the `numpy.any()` function but it seems is not working the way I thought, for example:

```
import numpy as np
z = np.array([1, 2000, 30000])
if np.any(z)>2:
   print('Something')
```

But the results return `False`

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542240/easy-way-to-test-if-each-element-in-an-numpy-array-lies-between-two-values I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work as I expected, so I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

So I've made it with the `any` function:

```
import numpy as np

z = np.array([1, 2000, 3.2e+18])
if (any(x>1000 fo x in z)):
    # do something
```