# Masking array to count value within 2 conditions

Tags: python, numpy

If I want to count values in a array less then 8 I can do:

```
(arr < 8).sum()
```

But how I can get the sum of values greater than 2 and less then 5:

I tried:

```
(2 < arr < 5).sum()
```

But I got this error:

```
ValueError:  The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambigous.
```

How can I perform this sum?
Thanks

Comment: I assume you're using NumPy, so I added the [tag:numpy] tag for you. If that's incorrect, you can [edit] to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Easy way to test if each element in an numpy array lies between two values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542240/easy-way-to-test-if-each-element-in-an-numpy-array-lies-between-two-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `and` `&`:

```
((arr > 2) & (arr < 5)).sum()
```